# mysqlsh to dump and load full schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I want to use mysqlsh to do the following:

1. Dump the FULL schema of a given database (not just tables, but functions, triggers, everything related to this database schema, same as `mysqldump -R DATABASE > DATABASE.sql`)
2. Load this full schema into a brand new database I just created (similar to `mysql --database=NEWDATABASE < DATABASE.sql`)

When I run `mysqlsh --execute 'util.dumpTables("DATABASE", [], "SQL/DATABASE", {all:true});'`, it of course just dumps the tables, and this can easily be imported into a brand new database with this command `mysqlsh --database=NEWDATABASE --execute 'util.loadDump("SQL/DATABASE", {schema: 'NEWDATABASE', ignoreVersion:true,resetProgress:true});`.  The problem is it is missing the functions and stored procedures.

So then I tried `mysqlsh --execute 'util.dumpSchemas(["DATABASE"], "DATABASE");'`, and then load it into a new DB with `mysqlsh --database=NEWDATABASE --execute 'util.loadDump("DATABASE", {dryRun: true, ignoreVersion:true});'`, but I instantly notice that it is trying to load into the original database, not my new database.  So how do I load it into a NEW database, one with a totally different name?

In case you are wondering, I am trying to learn how to maximize mysqlsh for my use case.  So the old `mysqldump` is not an option in this case.

Comment: I think you're trying to be more clever than `mysqldump`, which is probably not going to work. Your intent to "maximize `mysqlsh`" seems aspirational, not necessarily practical.

Comment: mysqldump does not work great when moving between different MySql versions, mysqlsh does, thus what I am doing.  This is why I said mysqldump is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will just have to edit the `.sql` file(s) with a text editor before you try to load it.

This tool is really for dumping schemas and importing them to a different MySQL instance, but leaving the schema names unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple string substitution at the beginning of the dumpfile might suffice.

Just replace
`"use olddatabase;"`

with
`"use newdatabase;"`

and you are done. Unless your SQL code, e.g. stored procedures and view definitions contain some fancy inter-database commands, such as (I'm making this up).... `select u.name, u.id from olddatabase.users u inner join somedatabase.tokens t on u.id = t.id where...` Then you would need to perform proper string substitutions here as well.